Connecting to MSSQL Server database using pyspark
I am new to pyspark and trying to connect to mssql server database. Here are the details:
This gets printed when I run the script I have.
('Processing table:', u'POL_ACTION_AMEND')
('Table schema:', u'dbo')
('Source_database:', u'PRD01_IPS')
('SQL Query:', '(SELECT TOP 100 * FROM PRD01_IPS.dbo.POL_EVENT_HISTORY)')
('jdbc_uri:', 'jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://REPLCLPRD01\REPL/PRD01_IPS')

But spark.read.format() is throwing an error when trying to load the data from the table.
select_statement_sql_server = "(SELECT TOP 100 * FROM {source_database}.{schema}.{table_name})"


# Read data for a table 
data_df = (
    spark.read.format("jdbc")
        .option("url",source_jdbc_uri)
        .option("user",source_jdbc_user)
        .option("password",source_jdbc_pass)
        .option("driver", source_jdbc_driver)
        .option("dbtable", select_statement_sql_server.format(
            source_database=source_database, schema=schema, table_name='POL_EVENT_HISTORY'
        ))
        .load()
)
    
data.show()

The error I am getting is:
('SQL Query:', '(SELECT TOP 100 * FROM PRD01_IPS.dbo.POL_EVENT_HISTORY)')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pkg/lxd0bigd/Talend_To_Pyspark/PSTAR_IPS/200job_IPS.py", line 136, in <module>
    .option("dbtable", select_statement_sql_server.format(source_database=source_database, schema=schema, table_name='POL_EVENT_HISTORY')) \
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.8-1.cdh7.1.8.p0.30990532/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 172, in load
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.8-1.cdh7.1.8.p0.30990532/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.8-1.cdh7.1.8.p0.30990532/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-7.1.8-1.cdh7.1.8.p0.30990532/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o236.load.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:243)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:231)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

I have a shell script to run the script which has spark-submit command.
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client \
    --driver-class-path ${DRIVER_AND_JAR_FILE_PATH} \
    --jars ${DRIVER_AND_JAR_FILE_PATH},${JAR_FILE_XML} \
    --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true" \
    --conf "spark.yarn.dist.files=/etc/hive/conf.cloudera.hive/hive-site.xml" \
    ${ROOT_DIR}/200job_IPS.py \
    --hdfspath ${XML_FILE_HDFS} >> ${LOGFILE_DIR}/200job_log.txt 2>&1 

sh /pkg/lxd0bigd/Talend_To_Pyspark/PSTAR_IPS/Ingestion_PSTAR.sh dev \
    /pkg/lxd0bigd/Talend_To_Pyspark/spark-jobs/lib/mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre7.jar

The DRIVER_AND_JAR_FILE_PATH is what I am not sure about. I have 3 jar files and I am not sure which to be used. I tried all 3, and the same issue exists.
mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre7.jar, sqljdbc41.jar, jtds-1.3.1-patch.jar
Any suggestions and solutions will be greatly helpful.

Did you copy this code / example from somewhere? The dbtable option should just be the table name, not a query. You would use expr function for the select statement

@OneCricketeer I have the same code for the Oracle database which works, and was trying to use the same.

I had to check the docs again... So, are you trying to select from 100 tables at once? Oracle and sql server have different syntax. Does that query actually work directly in sql server? From the Spark docs - "Note that when using dbtable... anything that is valid in a FROM clause of a SQL query can be used. For example, instead of a full table you could also use a subquery in parentheses". And if so, why printing Processing table:', u'POL_ACTION_AMEND'?

@OneCricketeer Yes, the query works in MS SQL server. I am getting the top 100 rows from the table. I have a big query with 4-5 lines which does not work, so I am testing with a simple select * from table statement. The query I have runs in a loop for more than 50 tables. so, the database name and table name are parameterized.

And each of those row values are valid table names within the database? In other words, how is POL_ACTION_AMEND table being processed if its value not used?

Yes these are valid tables within the database. I have edited the question. To include the sql_server_statement

Spark is going to run the equivalent of SELECT * FROM (SELECT TOP 100 * FROM PRD01_IPS.dbo.POL_EVENT_HISTORY)' rather than selecting from only one table. Is that what you're expecting and does that query work?


Use .option("query", select_statement_sql_server....) instead of dbtable, shouldn't make a difference, but that's the right thing to do. 2. Assuming there is some bug in driver, have you tried a different version of the driver jar? You also don't have to download the driver, you can ask spark-submit to download it for you, e.g. --packages com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:23.2.0.0,io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.0 for Oracle driver and DeltaLake lib.


@Kashyap This is for MSSQL server, not oracle. And I am using Hadoop pyspark. Just to give more info.

It's an example. You obviously need to find the driver for your DB/version and specify that, not Oracle.

what's your DB hostname? what is \REPL? Is port number optional in URL?

Found the solution.

Had to chnage the jdbc uri to "jdbc:sqlserver://REPLCLPRD01\REPL;databaseName=PRD01_IPS"

Chnage the driver to mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre7.jar

If we use .option("query"), the select statement can be as is.
If we use option(dbtable), the select statement should be within brackets and should have an alias.


"(SELECT TOP 100 * FROM {source_database}.{schema}.{table_name}) tmp"

My first guess is that your url is malformed. Not sure what that \REPL is.
Try:
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://REPLCLPRD01/PRD01_IPS
or
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://REPLCLPRD01:<custom-port-if-applicable>/PRD01_IPS
See this answer for reference.
Also as I commented query option is more appropriate in this case than dbtable. Although that's not the cause your NPE.
.option("query", select_statement_sql_server....)
